# ADF Copy Dynamic Datatype Change in Loop for multiple table

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I have to load multiple master tables from SQL Server to Azure ADLS using ADF. While loading I have to change the datatype of all column which are timestamp to string in a for each loop. Can this is possible using ADF ?

I tried for each loop of ADF, in that I used Copy data and tried to change the mapping configuration to map the timestamp datatype to string but was unable to do so.

Comment: What type of file are you writing to in ADLS? Many file formats (TXT, CSV etc.) Dont have datatypes in them. Files such as Parquet do have limited datatypes. You can try casting your data in your select statement like this: `SELECT FORMAT(YourDateColumn,'yyyy-MM-dd') as YourDateColumn FROM MyTable`

Comment: Also keep in mind "unable to do so" isn't really suffiicent info to help out.

Comment: I would suggest creating a SQL file containing the SELECT statement and adding casting in the SELECT statement itself and then saving these files in the ADLS as a configuration. Then read the files from ADLS in ADF loop over each file and store the data in ADLS using the COPY data.

Comment: @NadeemKhan, Thank you for your reply ....that can be one solution...but i wanted something in ADF itself.

Comment: @Nick.Mc, Thank you for your reply ... I am writing to parquet file...I tried to use mapping but i couldn't find a generic way to just map the column datatype. I could map the predefined schema but the all master tables  have different schema.

Comment: Why are you changing timestamp to string? This is a bad idea. But if you want to proceed, just cast it in the select statement as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if your schema is same for all the master tables then it will automatically Change the data type to string if you specified it in mapping.

If you are creating file dynamically it will automatically store the data as string when it is (CSV or txt file)

[image]

IF schema is not same for all tables, then as @Nadeem said create SQL file with all your SQL statements including conversion/ casting of timestamp column and add it into ADLS.

`Convert()` function: To convert a datetime to a string, you use the function as follows:

```
SELECT id, event_name,CONVERT(varchar(50),event_datetime,126)  as event_datetime FROM sample_table2;
```

[image]

then lookup the file using lookup activity

Lookup Output:

[image]

and loop over it with each query to copy the table with conversion on timestamp column.

[image]

Copy activity source setting:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, i missed to add that schema is different for all tables. Thank you for your reply !!